# Quantifying intensity of brown color in camera images of apples

Tags: image-processing, color

I need help, I have images of apples and I would like to tell differences of browning color using Mathematica -- I am a just raw amateur with the software. How do I go about this challenge?

Comment: How about posting a sample picture and show us how you are approaching the problem?

Comment: Can we use this [image](http://cdnjust1neptr3ats.printabletreats.com/main-images/apple-clipart-in-shades-of-brown.jpg) as an example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating with a random image ...

```
img = Import["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Apple Shades of Brown.png"]
```

[image]

The variable `pixels` is to capture the positions of the pixels. And the [`PixelValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelValue.html) function is to get the corresponding RGB color.

```
pixels = {{100, 240}, {296, 240}, {98, 90}, {295, 90}};
PixelValue[img, pixels[[#]]] & /@ Range[4]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0.270588 & 0.180392 & 0.0588235 & 1. \\
>  0.533333 & 0.329412 & 0.0431373 & 1. \\
>  0.521569 & 0.403922 & 0.262745 & 1. \\
>  0.780392 & 0.552941 & 0.231373 & 1. \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

In this site ([Shades of Brown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_brown)), you will find the brown level classification that these apples fit ...

[image]